# Adicionar um objeto a um arrey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Estou tentando concatenar vários objetos para que ele formam um único arrey no meu projeto angular.
Irei mostra um pouco do código

```
selectFedd(user,feed){
      const key = user[0].userQueEuSigo
      feed.forEach(element => {
        if(element.keyUser == 2){
          this.publicacoes = [
              {
                keyUser:element.keyUser,
                id: element.id,
                user: element.user,
                photoUser:element.photoUser,
                photoPost: element.photoPost,
                curtidas: element.curtidas,
                comentarios: element.comentarios,
                pessoasQueCurtiu: element.pessoasQueCurtiu,
                totalComentarios:element.totalComentarios,
                like:element.like
              }
          ]
          console.log(this.publicacoes)
        }
      });
  }
```

essa função recebe como pare metro um arrey com vários objetos e nesse arrey eu seleciono apenas os que tem a keyUser == 2, ate ai tudo bem pois se eu executo so isso e dou um console.log, me retorna todas as 5 publicações que tem como keyUser o valor 2. Porem esse retorno são 5 objetos e eu estou com dificuldades para adicionar esses 5 objetos na minha variavel de nome publicacoes.

Vou deixar o meu publicacoes.model.ts aqui.

```
export interface Publicacao {
  keyUser: number,
  id: string,
  user:string,
  photoUser: string,
  photoPost: string,
  curtidas: number,
  comentarios: any[],
  pessoasQueCurtiu: any[],
  totalComentarios: number,
  like: boolean
}
```

no meu component.ts a minha variável está assim ::: publicacoes: Publicacao[] ela está como arrey pois estou iterando nela no meu template com o ngFor.

feed.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Publicacao } from './publi/publi.model';
import { TestService } from '../test.service';
import { UserPrincipal } from './userPrincipal.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-feed',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {

  publicacoes: Publicacao[]
  feedFull: Publicacao[]
  userPrincipal: UserPrincipal[]

  constructor(private testeService: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
//essa função pega todos os usuarios registrados no banco de dados Firebase
    this.testeService.read_userPrincipal().subscribe(data => { 
      this.userPrincipal = data.map(object => {
      return{
        token: object.payload.doc.id,
        bios: object.payload.doc.data()['bios'],
        id: object.payload.doc.data()['id'],
        imagePerfil: object.payload.doc.data()['imagePerfil'],
        nome: object.payload.doc.data()['nome'],
        seguidores: object.payload.doc.data()['seguidores'],
        seguindo: object.payload.doc.data()['seguindo'],
        totalPublicacoes: object.payload.doc.data()['totalPublicacoes'],
        user: object.payload.doc.data()['user'],
        userQueEuSigo: object.payload.doc.data()['userQueEuSigo'],
        publicacoes: object.payload.doc.data()['publicacoes']
      };})
        this.checkFollower(this.userPrincipal)
      });
  }
//essa checkFllower verifica se é um seguidor e retorna todas as publicações.
  checkFollower(primaryUser){
    const idPrimaryUser = 1//OK
    for(let i = 1; i < primaryUser.length; i++){ // for ta OK
      var arrey = primaryUser[i].userQueEuSigo
      if(arrey.indexOf(idPrimaryUser) == 0){
        this.testeService.carregar_publicacao().subscribe(data => {
          this.feedFull = data.map(publiObject => {
            return{
              keyUser: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['keyUser'],
              id: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['id'],
              user: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['user'],
              photoUser: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['photoUser'],
              photoPost: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['photoPost'],
              curtidas: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['curtidas'],
              comentarios: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['comentarios'],
              pessoasQueCurtiu: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['pessoasQueCurtiu'],
              totalComentarios: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['totalComentarios'],
              like: publiObject.payload.doc.data()['like']
            };})
              this.selectFedd(this.userPrincipal,this.feedFull)
           })
      }else{
        console.log('foi direto pro else')
      }
    }
  }

//essa é onde eu quero separar apenas as que tem a keyUser == 2
  selectFedd(user,feed){
      const key = user[0].userQueEuSigo
      feed.forEach(element => {
        if(element.keyUser == 2){
          this.publicacoes.push(element)
        }else{
          console.log('erro')
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Arquivo service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Injectable()

export class TestService {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
  /* create_NewIcecream : Cria um novo registro na coleção especificada usando o método add */
  criar_novo_user(record) {
    return this.firestore.collection('user').add(record);
  }
  /*read_Icecream: Chama o método snapshotChanges , que obterá registros e também será registrado para receber atualizações */
  read_userPrincipal(){
    return this.firestore.collection('user').snapshotChanges();
  }
  carregar_publicacao(){
    return this.firestore.collection('feed').snapshotChanges();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não compreendeu direito as ferramentas que está utilizando, quando faz o **forEach()** e o **if()** vc já tem os objetos que precisa vindos da Api, não precisa criar o objeto passando as propriedades como fez, no caso aí seria apenas dar push. Adaptei um exemplo só pra demonstrar como pode ser feito com Vanilla para replicar aí com Angular:

```js
let publicacoes = [];                  // sua variável publicações 
let api = [                            // seria todos os objetos vindos da api
  {keyUser: 'ok', id: 1, user: 'Fulano'},
  {keyUser: 'no', id: 2, user: 'Ciclano'},   // esse não bate na condição do if
  {keyUser: 'ok', id: 3, user: 'Beltrano'}
];

api.forEach(elem => {
  if(elem.keyUser == 'ok') publicacoes.push(elem)  // insere no array os objetos
})

console.log(publicacoes)
```

Na classe do componente Angular seria basicamente:

```
public publicacoes: Publicacao;

selectFedd(user,feed){
  const key = user[0].userQueEuSigo
  feed.forEach(element => {
    if(element.keyUser == 2) this.publicacoes.push(element) 
  });
  console.log(this.publicacoes)
}
```

Comment: ```
  selectFedd(user,feed){
      const key = user[0].userQueEuSigo
      feed.forEach(element => {
        if(element.keyUser == 2){
          this.publicacoes.push(element)
        }else{
          console.log('erro')
        }
      });
  }
```
usando desse modo não está funcionando, pois retorna o seguinte erro

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

desculpa pela demora

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando o feed.compent.ts e o test.service.ts completos

Comment: Estranho João, pq pelo erro que comentou não está achando a variável publicacoes. Aí realmente não sei o que seria!

Comment: viu a pergunta atualizada , ta foda esse erro kkkk

Comment: sabe como faz para pegar direto a publicação pela key no firebase?

Comment: pq eu poderia pegar direto pela key sabe

Comment: Putz não manjo nada de firebase, mas, já tentou tirar o tipo da variável e atribuir um array normal pra ver se vai tipo assim: **publicacoes = [ ]**

Comment: caraca kkk funcionou man funcionou carregou todas certinho, muito obrigado!!!! Estou refazendo o feed do instagram ja me resolveu um puta erro, so que não estou fazendo gerenciamento de sessão é só o feed mesmo. Muito obrigado

Comment: Legal que deu certo João, sucesso aí!